# Get data From Remote Domain

Tags: perl, api, cgi

Is it possible to get remote data from one domain to another via a perl script?

I don't want to get into a security discussion, just looking for a work example of getting remote server data.

Remote Script:

```
sub GetPageData{ 

  $PageData = 'Hello World';
}
```

Local script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";  
our $PageData;

require("http://MyDomain.com/cgi-bin/test.pl");
GetPageData();

print "$PageData";
```

Comment: If you want to pass data between servers, then use a **data format**, don't pass code. Data formats are much safer and **easier to deal with**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure ['our'](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) is really what you want. in my experience 'our' is rarely used when scripting but can come in handy when doing OO perl.

as to your request:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET, $url );
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 5 );
my $res = $ua->request( $req );
return unless $res->is_success;
my $page_data = $res->content;
```

Comment: The question seems to be asking about how to import code from a remote server, then execute it to populate a variable.

Comment: true, "remote server data" could mean a lot of things. but in the absence of a security discussion GET is our friend. :)

Comment: The question has example code in it that shows an attempt to import raw Perl from an HTTP URI.